# MVC ActionResult to force JQuery Mobile to refresh the page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile, actionresult

I have a MVC3 project using jQuery Mobile and I have a slight issue where when I return an action result to a view, jQuery Mobile is not reloading the page and therefore the `<script>` tags within the `<head>` are not being loaded?

I had the same issue when redirecting to another page in jQuery Mobile and could fix this by adding `rel="external"` to the a tag.

Is there anyway I can force the page to be reloaded within the action result?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your action result..

```
window.location = 'your full path';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the page and set this flag in the `options` object:

> **reloadPage** (*boolean*, default: false) Forces a reload of a page, even
>   if it is already in the DOM of the page container. Used only when the
>   'to' argument of changePage() is a URL.

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/methods.html*

Example:

```
<a data-role="button" href="/do-something.aspx">Click ME</a>
<script>
//bind to link elements for the click event
$('a').on('click', function () {
    //manually change page to the clicked HREF
    $.mobile.changePage(this.href, {
        //set the reloadPage flag to true so jQuery Mobile will update the page
        reloadPage : true
    });
    //stop the default behavior of the link
    return false;
});
</script>
```

By default jQuery Mobile looks first at the current DOM to see if a version of the requested page exists, if it does, jQuery Mobile just navigates to that page without loading any more external assets.